# Convert string to xml valid text in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, xml-validation

I need a way to convert a string to xml valid text in Coldfusion. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Might help if you posted more specifics. Like the string you have and the xml you want.

Comment: I'm not sure of the best method, be it regex, etc? So I want to keep it open ended by not posting any code. My goal is to get a solution that will replace all invalid special characters with valid xml code or remove them if no such alternative exists.

Comment: This was actually my last resort after spending quite a bit of time on google scouring forums and documentation. I just didn't know what I was looking for but thank you for the answer, you are a scholar and a gentlemen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
#XmlFormat(MyStringThatHasCrapInIt)#
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`#xmlParse(xml_string)#`

Comment: Granted there were not a lot of details in the OP, but I think his goal was something different. It sounds like he needed to "escape" some values *within* an xml string, rather than parse an xml string.